# How to map render components that come from a JS Object without a temporary variable to hold them in?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I came across some interesting code and I was wondering if its possible to "sugarize" it.

The components come as:

```
const sections = {
  Home: dynamic(() => import("./Sections/Home")),
  Example: dynamic(() => import("./Sections/Example")),
};
```

And then they are being rendered as:

```
export default function Page({ page }) { 

  return (
    <main>
      {page.sections.map((section, index) => {
        const SectionComponent = sections[section.type] || null;

        return (
          <SectionComponent
            key={`${pageKey}-${index}`}
            id={index}
            fields={section.fields}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
}
```

So what would be the syntax to directly render

```
sections[section.type]({id: index, fields: section.fields})
```

to do something like this within the map, to reduce the code, without the `SectionComponent` variable in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sections[section.type]({id: index, fields: section.fields})

There is not much to gain from what you suggest, on the contrary, in the above code now you are **calling the component as a function** vs **rendering it as an element** as it was before, those are different things.
In most of the cases you want to render it as element, otherwise you may get some unexpected behavior especially with hooks.

The code you came across is the [recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) approach to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't even know if the above code will work, I just freestyled it while writing the past, I was just wondering if its possible and if it is a good idea to do it. But I believe you answered that question :)

Comment: @Darkbound Check the updated answer

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava thanks for the KCD reference.  I removed my answer, TIL!